# Comparing struct in c++

Tags: c++, data-structures, struct, comparison-operators

Do anyone know a *general method* to declare a comparision function for **struct** so that I can use it in **sort , priority queue , map ,set ...**

I would also know how to specify the comparision function when declaring a data structure (like map ) having a structure as a key (in the case where i have two or more comparision functions)

Thank you in advance

Comment: What should a "general method" to compare structs look like? `std::tie` is a good option for quickly defining comparisons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comparison function depends from the *semantics* of your struct. What does it mean that `a < b` for your type?

In general, a compare function is something along the line of this (references are optional):

```
bool comp( const YourType& a, const YourType& b );
```

To make a map use your compare function, you must write like this:

```
#include <map>

struct YourType{
    int v;
};

struct YourTypeComparison{
    bool operator()( const YourType& a, const YourType& b ) { return a.v < b.v; }
};

int main()
{
    std::map<YourType,int, YourTypeComparison> m;
}
```

Comment: hello thank you for your answer  i does work with map , but it seems not to work whith priority queue   here is my declaration :                                          
std::priority_queue<YourType,vector<YourType>,YourTypeComparison> m;

Comment: @MohamedFadhelOmar It compiles fine to me. Have you included <vector> and <queue>? And try to write std::priority_queue<YourType,std::vector<YourType>,YourTypeComparison> m; (note the std:: before "vector")

Comment: @MohamedFadhelOmar You are wellcome! You may want to accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

How can the method be "general"?

Let's say you have this struct.

```
struct MyStruct{
    A a; // A is your own class
};
```

How would the compiler know how to compare objects of type A?

You need to define a comparison operator yourself.

```
bool operator()(const MyStruct& s1, const MyStruct& s2);
```

This function can be given as a compare-function when creating for example a std::map.

```
explicit map (const key_compare& comp = key_compare(),
          const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

[std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/map/)

> comp: Binary predicate that, taking two element keys as argument, returns true if the first argument goes before the second argument in the strict weak ordering it defines, and false otherwise.

defaults to

```
less<key_type>
```

Comment: hello i tried this code but  i had an error saying that the comparing fuction must have only one argument

Comment: Then you´re doing something incorrectly. Can you post the code where you try to use it? It should be a binary predicate taking TWO arguments.

Comment: If you implement the operator as a member function it takes only one argument. If you implement it as an external function (friend) then it takes two.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a friend, members are public by default in structs.

Comment: i changed the place of the function (out of the struct ) and it worked , do you to have more than one function ?

Comment: No, you only give one function as the binary predicate. This function defines the strict weak ordering of the object type (in this case your struct).

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use the standard containers like `std::map< std::string, int >`. But they also have a `Comparator` type and an `Allocator` type.

The Comparator used by default is `std::less`, which looks somewhat like this,

```
template <class T>
struct less : binary_function <T,T,bool> {
    bool operator() (const T& x, const T& y) const {
        return x<y;
    }
};
```

(There are some other already made functors http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional)

Notice that it compares two objects with `<`. This means that as a "general method" you only need to implement the operator `bool operator< (const X& lhs, const X& rhs){...}` to allow your objects to be sorted. See [Operator Overloading FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading). As a rule of thumb, if you're going to implement one comparison operator then you should implement the others too.

If you need to sort your keys in another way you can define your own comparator (functor).

```
template < class T >
struct myLess {
    bool operator()( const T& lhs, const T& rhs ) const {
        return lhs < rhs;
    }
};
```

And use it in a map like `std::map< int, int, myLess<int> >`.

You can also not use templates at all if you only need to compare one type.

```
struct myLess {
    bool operator()( const int& lhs, const int& rhs ) const {
        return lhs < rhs;
    }
};
```

Then you only have to write `std::map< int, int, myLess >`.

Keep in mind that the objects you're comparing are the Key types, not necessarily the Contained types.